# emacs mail: sendmail-query-once fails

Tags: email, emacs

When using compose-mail to write a messages, and then using message-send-and-exit to send the message, I got a failure.  In the messages buffer, I see:

```
Sending via mail...
sendmail-query-once: Symbol's function definition is void: nil
```

Running "version" gives: "GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7) of 2014-03-07 on lamiak, modified by Debian."

Comment: Where is `sendmail-query-once` defined? Which Emacs version? Do you see the same behavior with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Is the variable `send-mail-function` set to `nil`?  You could set it to to `sendmail-query-once`, to go through the mail sending method selection once again.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, it works when I do emacs -Q.

Comment: @legoscia Yes, send-mail-function is set to nil in the emacs that I use.  I set it to sendmail-query-once, and went through the setup, and everything works. Want to write up as a solution? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the variable `send-mail-function` has been set to `nil` for some reason.  The function `sendmail-query-once` expects this variable to contain the name of a function that will send the message.  Since `nil` is not a valid function, you get the error "Symbol's function definition is void: nil".

As a special case, if `send-mail-function` is set to `sendmail-query-once`, then you will be taken to a prompt for setting up sending email.  Try setting it to that value, to go through the method selection again, and then the configuration will be saved automatically.